# Word to denote time to expiration

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a single word to denote the amount of time before something expires? For example:

> The password is valid for another 10 hours

What's the word that is equivalent to "good for a period of" ?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: You could say the password has a half-life of 5 hours :D

Comment: @V0ight LOL, but nope. You'd still have a portion left after 10 hours that way. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different words can be used for this. In terms of lifespan (itself such a word), ***[longevity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/longevity)*** is often used: "the length or duration of life." In terms of products, we often use ***[shelf life](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shelf-life)***: "the term or period during which a stored commodity remains effective, useful, or suitable for consumption."

Answer (score 4):

You could use the word [**lifetime**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20lifetime):

> the duration of a thing's existence or usefulness.
>
> *"a plan to extend the lifetime of satellites"*

"The password has a lifetime of 10 hours."

"The password's lifetime is 10 hours."

"The lifetime of the password is 10 hours."

Answer (score 4):

*The password has a **lifespan** of 10 hours.*

**Lifespan** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lifespan)

> *noun* The length of time for which a person or animal lives or a thing functions

From [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTFWV_5.1.0/com.ibm.itim.doc/usr_oracleebs_5129.htm)

> *"The password lifespan specifies the period of time before the password of a user account expires."*